# Stress-energy tensor spin-1 coupling

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, quantum-spin, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Would it be possible for the stress-energy tensor ($T_{\mu\nu}$) to couple to a spin-1 anti-symmetric rank-2 field (like the electromagnetic field strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$)? If so, what would be the Lagrangian? The thing is that the stress-energy tensor usually couples to a spin-2 field (like graviton), so I was wondering whether it could couple to a spin-1 rank-2 field as well.

Comment: Note that $T^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=0$.

Comment: Yes, but potentially one can have $\epsilon^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ where $\epsilon^{\mu\nu}$ is an anti-symmetric tensor. Or, one might even have $F^{\alpha\beta}T_{\alpha\lambda}F^{\lambda}_{\beta}$.

Comment: That first expression doesn’t make sense. It violates the rules for tensor indices.

Comment: but the second one is possible.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn’t happen as far as we know.

Comment: If so, the question would be: why?

Comment: Why don’t you edit your question to ask that?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you couple a field to the stress energy tensor in the Lagrangian, then you modify the stress energy tensor. For example, in linearized gravity, the Lagrangian contains a coupling $h_{\mu\nu} T^{\mu\nu}$, where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the stress energy of the matter on flat space. However, the presence of this term itself modifies the stress energy tensor, so the original stress energy tensor is no longer conserved. To fix this, you need to add higher order terms in $h$, ultimately leading to "covariantizing" the theory (ie, replacing partial derivatives with covariant ones, and leading to a stress energy that is covariantly conserved). The fact that this "covariantization" procedure works is non-trivial and relies on the existence of an underlying diffeomorphism symmetry. If you tried a similar process with a spin-1 field, you would find that there isn't a self-consistent way to couple to a conserved stress energy tensor.
2. In gravity, a natural definition of the stress energy tensor is
   $$
   T_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_{\rm matter}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}
   $$
   Then the terms you have written down coupling the spin-1 field to other matter fields via some "zero-th order" stress energy tensor, would just be considered part of the matter action and contribute to the full stress energy tensor.
3. In general, attempts to think of the graviton as being made up of spin-1 fields run into an obstruction through the [Weinberg Witten theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem).

Comment: Thanks @Andrew.